# Function to ensure that at least one choice is selected

Tags: javascript, validation, angular.js, lodash.js

[image]

First here is my `settings` object below. `insight`, `spike` and `momentum` are binded to 3 checkboxes in the markup. The objective here is to prevent the user from deselecting all choices, 1 choice must remain selected.

```
var settings = {
    user_id            : 0,
    insight            : true,
    spike              : true,
    momentum           : true,
    all_tickers        : true,
    errorMsg           : false,
    port_tickers       : [],
    fav_tags           : [],
    sensitivity        : 'medium',
    email_notification : true
};
```

So what I'm doing below is I create an Array with just the 3 keys from the settings object I want. Next I filter that array down to only the keys that are set to true. Next if the checkbox model is the same as the last item in the `trueFilters` Array I can then send back `errorMsg = true`.

```
function updateFilters(type) {
    settings[type] = !settings[type];

    // Create Array of filters that are true
    var filterKeys = _.map(settings, function(filter, key) {
        if (key === 'insight' || key === 'spike' || key === 'momentum') {
            if (filter) {
                return key;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    });

    // Remove any filters that are null/false
    var trueFilters = _.remove(filterKeys, function(n) {
        return n != null;
    });

    // If this filter is the last, prevent user from unselecting
    if (trueFilters.length === 0) {
        settings[type] = !settings[type];
        settings.errorMsg = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (key === 'insight' || key === 'spike' || key === 'momentum') {
```

Instead of looping through and checking these specific keys using an `if`, why not just create an array with the keys you're interested in and loop through that?

```
var filterKeys = ['insight', 'spike', 'momentum'];
```

Running on this, you can easily use `map` to gather the values, `filter` to reduce to only those that are `true`. Then checking if it's the last `true` filter will just be a matter of checking if what remains from a `filter` is an array with 1 as length.

Additionally, this function can be made so that it doesn't introduce side-effects or reduces the surface area of a side-effect. You can simply split off the logic to another function and return a boolean, while leaving the logic with side-effects (one that alters `settings`) in the caller.

```
function isLastFilter(settings) {
  var filters = ['insight', 'spike', 'momentum'];

  return filters.map(filter => settings[filter])
                .filter(value => value === true)
                .length === 1;
}

function updateFilters(type) {
  var shouldUpdate  = !isLastFilter(settings);
  settings[type]    = shouldUpdate ? settings[type] : !settings[type];
  settings.errorMsg = !shouldUpdate;
}
```

On other things, `settings.errorMsg` shouldn't be part of the data. It's a computation of other settings. In this case, it's derived from a state where there's only one filter present. The problem here is that `updateFilters` is essentially a "sync" function, syncing `settings.errorMsg` to the state of the other settings. Lose this, and you'll get an invalid state.

Drop `settings.errorMsg`. If you're using an `ng-if` or something to toggle the error in the UI, it should be something like `ng-if="isLastFilter(settings)"`.